# Approximations to Radial Stress in a Spherical Shell

Tags: calculus, limits, approximation

Consider the following function

$$f_{\alpha}(\rho)=\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^3-1}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1+\alpha)^3}{\rho^3}\Big)\tag{1}$$

where $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^+$ is a parameter and $\rho$ is an independent variable which lies in $1\le\rho\le1+\alpha$. This function appears for the radial stress in a thick walled spherical shell and $\alpha$ represents the dimensionless thickness of the shell and $\rho$ is the dimensionless radial coordinate. For more details you can take a look at [this post on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/70637/stress-in-a-thick-walled-pressure-vessel).

My goal is to make an approximation of this function when $\alpha$ becomes too small, that is when the shell is too thin. If I take the limit $\alpha\to0^+$ then $\rho\to 1^+$ and $f_{\alpha}(\rho)\to+\infty$ so I get nowhere with this. I re-write this as follows

$$f_{\alpha}(\rho)=\frac{1}{\alpha}\frac{\alpha}{(1+\alpha)^3-1}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1+\alpha)^3}{\rho^3}\Big)\tag{2}$$

and I decide to take the limit of the coefficient of $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ in $(2)$ which leads to

$$f_{\alpha}(\rho)\approx \bar f_{\alpha}(\rho):=\frac{1}{\alpha}\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}\alpha f_{\alpha}(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\alpha}\tag{3}$$

This is the answer which is used in engineering text books.

Does my approach make sense? Is there a better way to make an approximation?

I think if we show that

$$\lim_{\alpha\to 0^+}\Big(f_{\alpha}(\rho)-\bar f_{\alpha}(\rho)\Big)=0 \tag{4}$$

then every thing seems fine.

Comment: I would just say that it blows up as $\alpha \to 0^+$, now $(1+\alpha)^3 \approx 1+3\alpha$ for small $\alpha$, so the denominator is like $3\alpha$ to leading order. To leading order the inside is like $3/2$, so to leading order the whole thing is like $\frac{1}{2\alpha}$. This is the same as what you wrote but the computation is simpler. I think your goal of $f_\alpha - \overline{f}_\alpha \to 0$ may not be satisfied in this case because you've only gotten things right to leading order, not to order $1$.

Comment: @Ian: So, how can I obtain an $\bar f_{\alpha}$ which satisfies the last requirement? The last requirement is a usual criteria which the asymptotes should satisfy.

Comment: You will need a sharper asymptotic for the behavior of $\rho$ than you have given in the problem. For instance it would be sufficient to provide $\rho'(0)$.

Comment: @Ian: Can you work out the details in answer for me please!? :)

Comment: Can I assume that $\rho'(0)$ is given (and finite)?

Comment: @Ian: $\rho$ is an independent variable. Is is not a function of $\alpha$ but it just lies in the aforementioned interval. :)

Comment: Based on [this answer on Mathematica.SE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15035/863), we can define `f[a_, p_] := 1/((1 + a)^3 - 1) (1 + 1/2 (1 + a)^3/p^3);` and then run `Normal[Series[f[a t, (p - 1) t + 1], {t, 0, 1}]] /. t -> 1` to get the approximation $$f_\alpha(\rho) \approx 1 - \rho + \frac{\alpha}{3} + \frac{4-5\rho+2\rho^2}{2\alpha}.$$

Comment: @AntonioVargas: Why did you introduce a new variable $t$? :)

Comment: To get around a quirk of Mathematica. See the answer I linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Probably off-topic but too long for a comment.*

If we consider
$$f=\frac{1}{(1+\alpha)^3-1}\Big(1+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(1+\alpha)^3}{\rho^3}\Big)$$ where $\rho$ is a constant, a simple Taylor series built at $\alpha=0$ would give
$$f=\frac{\frac{1}{\rho ^3}+2}{6 \alpha }+\frac{1}{3} \left(\frac{1}{\rho
   ^3}-1\right)+\frac{1}{9}   \left(\frac{1}{\rho ^3}+2\right)\alpha+O\left(\alpha
   ^2\right)$$ For sure, the problem becomes more complex if $\rho$ depends on $\alpha$.

Taking into account the bounds, let us define $\rho=1+\phi(\alpha)$ with $\phi(0)=0$. This would lead to
$$f=\frac{1}{2 \alpha }-\frac{1}{2}\phi '(0)+ \left(\frac{1}{3}+\phi '(0)^2-\phi '(0)-\frac{1}{4}\phi ''(0)\right)\alpha+O\left(\alpha ^2\right)$$

Now, making series of series and using $\rho=x+1$, this would give
$$f=\frac{x^2-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{2}}{\alpha }+\left(2 x^2-x\right)+\frac{1}{3} 
    \left(2 x^2-x+1\right)\alpha+O\left(\alpha ^2\right)$$

Comment: (+1) Thank you Cluade. :) Indeed, $\rho$ does **not** depend on $\alpha$ but it always lies in $1\le\rho\le1+\alpha$. So, I think your second equation would be OK. What is the radius of convergence for the second equation? :) Another thing is that the approximations I see in the books does not involve any $\rho$!

Comment: One more question. $f$ does not seem to have a Taylor series around $\alpha=0$ as its values and derivatives are not defined at $\alpha=0$. How did you get the second equation? I assume by factoring $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ from $f$, right?

Comment: @H.R. It is not necessary fo consider $\alpha\,f$ but, if you prefer, this would be an "easier" way (you can extablish the series expansion of $\frac 1 {\sin(x)}$). For the second part, I made it as a power series in two variables (have a look at  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html in "Generalization & Extensions").

Comment: So, what I got is that we use a double Taylor series in $\alpha$ around $0$ and in $\rho$ around $1$ and we can get $f_\alpha(\rho)=\frac{1}{2\alpha}+O(\alpha (\rho-1))$. Right?

Comment: @H.R.. Yes, this is the idea. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series#Taylor_series_in_several_variables